# What parts of the Sitecore back-end are dependent on sitecore_master_index sitecore_web_index and sitecore_core_index

Tags: content-search

As per title; what functionality in the Sitecore back-end is dependent on the indexes

- `sitecore_master_index`
- `sitecore_web_index`
- `sitecore_core_index`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know only about 4 places where Sitecore built-in `sitecore_DB_index` indexes are used. Those are:

1. Search bar above the content tree in Content Editor:

[image]

2. Search tab in Content Editor:

[image]

3. Bucket search (similar to previous one):

[image]

4. `Multilist with search` fields

[image]

Comment: The listing of `Forms` in 9.0+ in the Experience Forms application is driven from index. More and more applications are directly relying on indexes these days.

Comment: @jammykam you are right, I totally forgot about forms. You may want to add it as another answer to the ticket.